# Will b always override a when setting (a || b) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, operators, operator-precedence

I'm trying to set some properties, which can either take a default value (`a`) or be overridden by another value (`b`). Both `a` and `b` may be undefined. I need to make sure, if `b` is specified, it will override the value set by `a`

Question:

Will this work by simply setting:

```
 foo: {
   param: a || b
 }
```

Or more specifically, if both `a` and `b` are defined, how can I make sure, `b` overrides `a`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's more complicated than that, but first thing to do is realize that "b" has to go first:

```
  param: b || a
```

If "b" has a value (is not `undefined`) and it's not `null`, `0`, `NaN`, `""`, or `false`, then the value of the "param" property will be set to the value of "b". The `||` operator works for situations like this so long as legitimate "good" values for "b" can't be a JavaScript "falsy" value.

Comment: ok. good explanation. I can make sure `b` is either something or undefined, so this should be ok. Thanks!

Comment: and by something I mean a string and not `null, 0, NaN, "" or false`

Answer (score 1):

> Or more specifically, if both `a` and `b` are defined, how can I make sure, `b` overrides `a`?

You swap the order of the operands.

```
foo: {
  param: b || a
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It short circuits to the value that first returns true. They do a good job of describing the logical (||) and other operands here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FLogical_Operators

Answer (score 1):

In general you can't solve this problem as written, because in Javascript too many values will be handled as "false"... For example, let's put

```
var b = 0;
var a = 5;
```

`0` is a good value, right? It isn't `undefined` or `null`. How much money do you have in your hand at this time? **0 $**? :-)

```
var res1 = b || a; // 5
var res2 = a || b; // 5
```

`0` can't overwrite anything :-) (the same for `""` and `false`, both good values that represent something)